# SQL query, from a third party software, on an MS Access database returning previous value, after every 10th query

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have my product(ShoreTel ECC).

ECC SQL Execute on Access databse, is returning a previous value, after every 10th query.

Scenario:
I have an Access db, which contains a table(say Table1), that has a single row and single column, and field name is "value".
I made an external db connection from my product to the Access db.

When I execute the following query:

Select * from Table1;

I see that, after every10 queries, it returns the older value. For 9 queries, it will give the right value.
After giving the wrong value on the 10th time, it will again give the right value on the 11th time.

Please let me know what should I be doing to solve this ?

Is it a known issue, with MS Access database ?

Comment: If you provide some `demo data` with `expected/unexpected result` it could help to help you better

Comment: You're obviously not giving us the full picture. What happens between the query executions?